# Getting error "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" while developing Alexa Skill through Alexa Developers Console?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

When testing out my skill using the Test Simulator for Alexa I am getting the following error:

"There was a problem with the requested skill's response"

I tried looking at solutions, but I could not find anything.

Below is my JSON Input 1 and I am not getting anything in JSON output.

Please help me here?

```
{
"version": "1.0",
"session": {
    "new": true,
    "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.8df6ac89-2811-43cf-8578-e9edc30fa091",
    "application": {
        "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.b1f0f00c-d3a9-43b9-82fe-92f066c58880"
    },
    "user": {
        "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AHNEWQLTUHO42PDYBLNORMFZURAPP5WSA52C6HPP4GEUM3MPBRYTY6WKULN3BNXIKPEOLUDQMX7EOLCG3E7LCD3YPJ4QL5JZ2N2UTX4UUFIWFY5PVGNSWC4JVO2EVFV5TDJD6HIPHU5O4KTSQW7XWBTUCSZ4JFPMFBPKEQ5IFLBZMXJI2XSRSMXKJV3PVJRSR5OT32LGO74AP2A"
    }
},
"context": {
    "System": {
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.b1f0f00c-d3a9-43b9-82fe-92f066c58880"
        },
        "user": {
            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AHNEWQLTUHO42PDYBLNORMFZURAPP5WSA52C6HPP4GEUM3MPBRYTY6WKULN3BNXIKPEOLUDQMX7EOLCG3E7LCD3YPJ4QL5JZ2N2UTX4UUFIWFY5PVGNSWC4JVO2EVFV5TDJD6HIPHU5O4KTSQW7XWBTUCSZ4JFPMFBPKEQ5IFLBZMXJI2XSRSMXKJV3PVJRSR5OT32LGO74AP2A"
        },
        "device": {
            "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AHUW3YVJLFTNIZQ7UUMLHULHQWHKPMW2UICHN4DZRBGBSYZJ3LMSUZLC4LP7Q5F4M7IXQOCAJ4KFNFB7GVAIRLIOHK7YN62XTX6LKRODFUKR2LP4RSGJUQCJGHXP7KIEFULCF6GVQD77DVPOC6OILLKGPEKADVW253ZEOJX4FGLG2SVWZMFHW",
            "supportedInterfaces": {}
        },
        "apiEndpoint": "https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com",
        "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.L0hwnl1wAddgWkZBxbu9Q4nRHlzwWglcSiqzf4Z_Nzg8C4XzsP9-5x_wccMpDWRPQxE5s0YOf6UfkCooakR36lVkm6Z7PhVqJShNrF6YooC29vjJ50C1-_wg27AwcDWXBG4c_tjDTFcrAuwkNOo3pBUjA9xE00a3q6Ecs-UtD-stQXoLv4J0f8bpe7AEpfc1pzaqhBXkybYYA91IFLVX67Gvxqiag2CwjdT6BO0uayQqZpXZd5F4IRfYuLmsqK0aFIJv5g0h_kfwPusowLkGneegE2uTLE5SwZpZkWg9-aI-6HvdvRe1DvZbgnJKjw2SBRNGdKT-UOkJZTndI3mgag"
    },
    "Viewport": {
        "experiences": [
            {
                "arcMinuteWidth": 246,
                "arcMinuteHeight": 144,
                "canRotate": false,
                "canResize": false
            }
        ],
        "shape": "RECTANGLE",
        "pixelWidth": 1024,
        "pixelHeight": 600,
        "dpi": 160,
        "currentPixelWidth": 1024,
        "currentPixelHeight": 600,
        "touch": [
            "SINGLE"
        ],
        "video": {
            "codecs": [
                "H_264_42",
                "H_264_41"
            ]
        }
    },
    "Viewports": [
        {
            "type": "APL",
            "id": "main",
            "shape": "RECTANGLE",
            "dpi": 160,
            "presentationType": "STANDARD",
            "canRotate": false,
            "configuration": {
                "current": {
                    "video": {
                        "codecs": [
                            "H_264_42",
                            "H_264_41"
                        ]
                    },
                    "size": {
                        "type": "DISCRETE",
                        "pixelWidth": 1024,
                        "pixelHeight": 600
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"request": {
    "type": "LaunchRequest",
    "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.b0de7b26-cfba-4942-92b4-d5589c7b8db3",
    "timestamp": "2020-03-29T15:21:35Z",
    "locale": "en-IN",
    "shouldLinkResultBeReturned": false
}
```

}

Comment: That is a generic alexa error response, what is the error your get from lambda logs

Comment: where I can see those ?

Comment: Go to lambda -> Monitoring -> View logs in cloudwatch

Comment: i am not using Lambda directly. Inside Alexa Developer Console, it is auto configured I think. Please check the latest comsole.